# xmlPrint function can't write annotations from "natlog" and "quote"

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am writing a java program to create a pipeline, annotate sentences, then call xmlPrint() to write to a xml file to be used by a python program. It seems annotations from some annotators are not written to the xml file while I can see the annotations in the debugger, for example "natlog" and "quote" annotators. Is there any function call to write all kinds of annotations produced in the xml file? Is this feature supported in CoreNLP.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment I do think some things are still missing from the xml output.  I will make a note to try to add these into the xml output for future versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. Very likely I will add some code to write some missing annotations into the xml output. After I get the permission from my boss, I will make the code open source. I will write a subclass so that my addition will be clearly separated. Thanks a lot for this wonderful toolkit.:)